# Open Second Activity when application resumes

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an app in which I have to use Fcaebook sdk for android. What I have to do is, when user successfully login in app, user moves to second activity. But, when user moves to home from second activity by pressing home button, and when user again clicks on the app icon from device, second activity should be there and not the login activity. Here is my code...

```
login.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(session.isOpened())
                {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), email + " " + user.getBirthday() , 1000).show();
                            Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Second.class);
                            in.putExtra("ID", user.getId());
                            startActivity(in);
                            Login.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

When I click on app icon after pressing home button from second activity, login activity starts with logout button. But I want to start second activity here. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

Do something in `onResume()` of LoginActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    if (session!=null&&session.isOpened()) {
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                email + " " + user.getBirthday(), 1000)
                                .show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Second.class);
                        in.putExtra("ID", user.getId());
                        startActivity(in);
                        Login.this.finish();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ketan...It's working fine. But when I click on app icon to start the app, Login activity opens first for 1 second and then Second activity starts...I want second activity when icon is pressed.

Comment: When you start app If user is not logged in then LoginActivity will open otherwise Second activity will opne.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your application logic from your activities.

I.e. store the user data in a static variable/singleton and check if user is already initialised and logged in. If so start second activity immediately

```
if (MyGlobalData.user == null) {
  login.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
  ...
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        MyGlobalData.user = user;
                        String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                        ...
} else {
   user = MyGlobalData.user;
   String email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
   ...  // start second activity immediately    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple and useful solution to return to closed (by HOME button) activity by app icon click.

Launch your application from new added activity (let's call it MainActivity). For that activity set in AndroidManifest.xml android:launchMode="singleInstance". In this activity start your activity which you wanted to run the first in the app. And after starting finish MainActivity (finish()). That's all. The example is provided below

```
<application
        android:name="com.myapp.android"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.android.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:name="com.myapp.android.LoginActivity"/>
```

...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Use a `SharedPreference`   `Boolen LOGGEDIN=true` if login is done.

then,

```
if (LOGGEDIN)
// Go To Second Activity
```

Comment: not sufficient, since you have this info in the status callback even though when the activity in resume.

Comment: Your answer is more vague. -1 until you not give a extense —or good— answer